# trying to create a bare-bones CocoaPods to share a few models but pod update doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, cocoapods

### EDIT #1

it looks like this worked:

```
pod update JTModels
```

---

I have two projects and want to share some models between them. I have created a sample project located here:

```
https://github.com/trestles/JTModels
```

and I have a sample project that has the following Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'JTModels', :git => 'https://github.com/trestles/JTModels.git'
```

the problem is that I bumped the Version number in my podspec to 0.0.5 but when I run pod update in my sample, it stayes at 0.0.4. Deleting out the Podfile.lock works but, to best of my knowledge, is not how this should be handled.

```
Mon Jan 26$ pod update
Update all pods
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.36.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Pre-downloading: `JTModels` from `https://github.com/trestles/JTModels.git`, commit `12ad2cc2912d69baed6898e11b78d54c52102ba5`
Downloading dependencies
Installing JTModels 0.0.2 (was 0.0.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Mon Jan 26$ less Podfile
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried `pod outdated` but same result.

Comment: Did you try pod install, that removes all outdated ones and adds new pods listed in podfile ?

Comment: yes, when I run `pod install` it seems to be stuck on 0.0.4 rather than 0.0.5 which I think is current. deleting Podfile.lock would bump it to 0.0.5

Comment: So, why dont you provide the version number in the pod itself.

pod 'JTModels', :git => 'https://github.com/trestles/JTModels.git', '~>0.0.5'

Comment: hmm... that's giving me an error pod 'JTModels', :git => 'github.com/trestles/JTModels.git';, '~>0.0.5' - would I have to specify a bumped version in the client app in that case?

Comment: Try this,

source 'github.com/trestles/JTModels.git'
pod 'JTModels', '~> 0.0.5'

Comment: ugh, still not working `Unable to find a specification for JTModels (~> 0.0.5)` - thx for help, have to run to lunch